# How to store decimal values as a varible

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite, pi

I'm writing a program that uses an infinite sum to calculate pi to a large number of decimal places very fast, 22 iterations results in 15 decimal places. However, due to limitations of python this is the maximum number of decimal places that can be shown. So try and fix this issue I looked to the internet and found [this website](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html) that included information on the python decimal class.

This seemed like the perfect solution to my problem, however when trying this method I could not add the numbers and save them to a variable. After going back to the original site to find an answer, I couldn't find anything involving variable. But the page is ludicrously long, and I could have easily missed something.

Here is my code, it works fine with out the decimal part:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 30

n = 0
value = 1 / 2
while True:
    n += 1
    top = 1
    bottom = 2 ** (2 * n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) * 2
    for i in range(n):
        top *= 2 * i + 1
        if i != 0: bottom *= 2 * i + 2

    value += Decimal(top) / Decimal(bottom)
    print(value * 6)
```

**EDIT:**
This is the error that I have recieved:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'
```

This is the first time that I have worked with this class and I am unsure how to contiune.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is because adding floats to decimals isn't supported, make `value` (the `float`) a `Decimal` first:

```
value = Decimal(1/2)
```

The error is explicit in telling you this, saying where the error originated, which operator caused it and what types it got.

Do take a look at the [Decimal FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq) provided in the docs for `decimal`, it has Q's you might be interested in if working with decimals.

Comment: Thank you, it seems so simple in hindsight! The program now works as intended.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was going to but I had to wait like 10 minutes, I have now though